# Who replaced Kinsey as Vice President?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the finale of Season 8, President Hayes informs Vice President Kinsey that he should "consider [his] resignation accepted". We later see that indeed, Kinsey is no longer the vice president.

Is there any indication in any canonical source who replaced him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We don't know /  it's not confirmed / it's not relevant.

There's no mention in the TV series, TV films, nor in any of the published novels regarding the identity of Kinsey's replacement. Since we know that President Hayes must have nominated a new VP [almost immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), it stands​ to reason that their identity must have been ***wholly irrelevant to the plot***.

After Kinsey's removal as VP, the President seems to have taken *personal* control of the Stargate project, liaising directly with Stargate Command. He also personally spearheads several diplomatic projects and meets with Earth's allies, a role previously taken by the VP.

My feeling was that given how disastrous Kinsey's interference proved in the Stargate Programme, it's a reasonable possibility that President Hayes may have decided to restrict the duties of the new VP to those [*normally associated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_President_of_the_United_States#Regular_duties) with the role. There's a possibility that they may have even have been unaware of the existence of the Stargate entirely.

Comment: Of course, is possible that the nominated VP was never confirmed by Congress, you know how they always screw up and delay any nomination hearings.

Comment: @cde - Hayes seems relatively popular and secure as a President. It's unlikely his nomination was held up for another 4 years.

Comment: You never know, congressmen would fight for years to be able to directly control who is VP. The first term VP pick could be delayed enough until the second term elections take place. But I digress :D